# IP address in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-2.0

Is there a way to get the IP address of a client in Silverlight if my Silverlight control is hosted in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there are no direct ways to do this. May be you can create a WebMethod to achieve this. Or some other tricks.

Check this thread, there are some suggestions: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/34744.aspx

Comment: yep! i knew about webservice method idea.... but i thought may be there is any other workaround....

Comment: But what is your opnion why this is a limitation in silverlight?

Answer (score -1):

Try the methods listed below (first one should usually do the trick), or see [here](http://michaelsync.net/2008/04/07/silverlight-2-beta1-url-referrer-screen-resolution-clients-data-time-and-ip-address) for more info.

```
Request.ServerVariables(”REMOTE_HOST”)
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
Request.UserHostAddress()
Request.UserHostName()
string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Comment: this is not for html.. its parameter passing in case of Asp.net.. this is not possible from HTML to my knowledge

Comment: @Chris I have tried all the methods, I am using ASP.Net (.asmx) web services with Silverlight. since there is no way to find client ip address in Silverlight, therefore I had to log this on service end. all the above methods work fine on my local system, but when i publish my service on production server. it starts giving errors.

Comment: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace: at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetAdditionalServerVar(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetServerVariable(String name)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.GetRemoteAddress()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_UserHostAddress()